# SwiftUI Can't Pass String to KeyPath

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-keypath

I have an app that references a large dataset that I load from an external public
site as a comma separated value file. I parse the data to a an array of a model called
WaterPointModel. An abbreviated version is:

```
struct WaterPointModel: Identifiable {

    let id = UUID()

    let STATE: String
    let COUNTY: String
    let AQWFrTo: Double
    let AQWGWSa: Double
    let AQWGWTo: Double
    //many more
}
```

I then want to summarize(reduce) the data. My function for this is:

```
func sumOnAttributeUSList(sumField: KeyPath<WaterPointModel,Double>) -> Double {
    return dataStore.waterPointModels.map({ $0[keyPath:sumField] }).reduce(0, +)
}
```

Next I want to call this to build a report:

```
let aqWFrTo = sumOnAttributeUSList(sumField: \.AQWFrTo)
```

This all works. However there are other reports where I need to pass a string to
create that keypath. Say I have a lookup table where I lookup "abc" and get "AQWFrTo". I
would like to do something like this in a loop:

```
let abc = "AQWFrTo"
let aqWFrTo = sumOnAttributeUSList(sumField: \WaterPointModel.abc)
```

I have not been able to make any version of this work. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Xcode 13.3.1, iOS 15.4

Comment: This is just Swift and is not related to SwiftUI, which is a UI framework built on the Swift language.

Comment: It is possible to get key path by string using Mirror ([see this discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/getting-keypaths-to-members-automatically-using-mirror/21207/4)) and then you can just overload your sum function with String argument.

Comment: Here is a result of experiments with different dynamic accesses to property [TestWays4DynamicMemberLookup.swift](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestWays4DynamicMemberLookup.swift)

Comment: Thanks, Asperi. That is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach is this:

```
func toKeypath(_ str: String) -> KeyPath<WaterPointModel,Double>? {  // <-- with or without optional
    switch str {
        case "AQWFrTo": return \.AQWFrTo
        case "AQWGWSa": return \.AQWGWSa
        case "AQWGWTo": return \.AQWGWTo
        // ...
        default: return nil  // <-- or a default Keypath
    }
}

let aqWFrTo = sumOnAttributeUSList(sumField: toKeypath("AQWFrTo"))
```

Comment: Super. This will work for me.